# Calling a non-modal dialog page passing IR report ID in page url

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to change all popup pages in an app from normal page template to non-modal-dialog page template in apex 5.1

I'll try to describe the complete use-case:

I have an Interactive report page with link columns for each record which opens a dialog window where users can edit/interact with the record.

The dialog has Previous/Next buttons to allow users to navigate through the records.

When a filter is set on the report, the dialog window should take this into account in the Next/Previous behavior.

For e.g. if the report filter selects only one row, then the dialog window Next/Previous buttons are disabled because there are no more rows shown by the report to navigate through.

For this functionalities, I need to pass the IR-report ID to the non-modal page.

Now the href property of the link column in the IR report should be something like:

```
javascript:apex.navigation.dialog('f?p=123:40:12345678:::40:P40_SIGNAL_DEF_ID,P40_IR_REPORT_ID,P40_MODE:42,41982451655076402,E&p_dialog_cs=NwEcqexhNPGD1VziCXol65xHCP8',{title:'SIGNALS_DIGITAL',height:'auto',width:'720',maxWidth:'960',modal:false,dialog:null},'t-Dialog-page--standard '+'',apex.jQuery('#myStaticID'));
```

Only two parts in this link I am concerned about. One is the checksum part `(p_dialog_cs=NwEcqexhNPGD1VziCXol65xHCP8)` and other part is the IR report ID(41982451655076402) I used `apex_util.prepare_url` function in the SQL query but this is not returning IR report ID something like :

```
javascript:apex.navigation.dialog('f?p=123:40:12345678:::40:P40_SIGNAL_DEF_ID,P40_IR_REPORT_ID,P40_MODE:42,,E&p_dialog_cs=NwEcqexhNPGD1VziCXol65xHCP8',{title:'SIGNALS_DIGITAL',height:'auto',width:'720',maxWidth:'960',modal:false,dialog:null},'t-Dialog-page--standard '+'',apex.jQuery('#myStaticID'));
```

I am not able to get the IR report ID here I tried using `$v("myStaticID_report_id")` inside this query but not working(though it is working in console)

So right now I am calling apex_util.prepare_url with dummy string say 'report_ID' the result I am passing to a javascript function as an argument. In javascript function, I am extracting the url part of the string(because I need the checksum value) and then replacing the dummy variable with `$v("myStaticID_report_id")` and then calling `apex.navigation.dialog` from there.

Now its functional but this needs to be repeated in almost 70 pages in my application. So I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You said, "For these functionalities, I need to pass the IR-report ID to the non-modal page." What do you mean by "IR-report ID"? Which ID are you after? Also, how do you intend to use the ID on the target page?

Comment: IR report ID is a 17 digit number (41982451655076402 in my case) referring to the Interactive Report. If we assign static ID of an Interactive Report as 'myStaticID' this number can be accessed by $v("myStaticID_report_id").

I have modified my question also. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I have a better idea of where you're getting this number from now. However, I still don't know what you intend to do with the number. Let's say you are able to pass it to P40_IR_REPORT_ID, what will you do with it on that page?

Comment: The non-modal dialog page has Previous & Next buttons to allow users to navigate through the records.
Say I have total of 1000 records and I filtered my interactive report page to display only 3 records. Then when I move to the non-modal page we need to navigate between only 3 of these records using the previous & next buttons and not all 1000 records. Also, I need to display the record number as '1 of 3' rather than '1 of 1000'. Each time I use the previous/next button records should be retrieved based on current filtering on the interactive report page.
Hope this brings clarity

Comment: I get all that. But how will you use the number passed to the page to implement all of that?